# AVCaptureSession not visible when using Sheet Dialog

Tags: swift, avcapturesession

I have a custom view in a storyboard with a ViewController to show me the output of a AVCaptureSessionPreviewLayer (in this case, webcam footage). When using a custom view in my normal window, all is fine and I see video output.

But when I want to use a custom view in a sheet dialog, the video is not visible even though the webcam indicates that is running.

Here is the ViewController code:

```
import Cocoa
import AVKit

class RecordViewController: NSViewController {

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
     var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?
     var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    @IBOutlet weak var camera: NSView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    camera.wantsLayer = true;
            camera.layer = CALayer()


            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.medium

            // Get all audio and video devices on this machine
            let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

            // Find the FaceTime HD camera object
            for device in devices {
                print(device)

                // Camera object found and assign it to captureDevice
                if ((device as AnyObject).hasMediaType(AVMediaType.video)) {
                    print(device)
                    captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                }
            }


            if captureDevice != nil {

                do {

                    try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!))
                    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                    previewLayer?.frame = (self.camera.layer?.frame)!

                    // Add previewLayer into custom view
                    self.camera.layer?.addSublayer(previewLayer!)

                    // Start camera
                    captureSession.startRunning()

                } catch {
                    print(AVCaptureSessionErrorKey.description)
                }
            }    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

`previewLayer?.frame = (self.camera.layer?.frame)!`

to:

`previewLayer?.frame = self.camera.bounds`

And if you want to make your camera fill your customView use this line too:

`previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill`